# Entity Framework - Oracle Column Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am having a problem with EF-Oracle usage.

I working on a DB in which an ID field is defined as NUMBER(5). The real value of the field in the DB starts with 95xxx. EF automatically defines this field as short which cannot be more than 32xxx. I cannot change the field type since there are lots of apps running based on the DB.

I am wondering if there is a way to dismiss the error in the Entity model side.

(I am using EF 5)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "EF automatically defines this field as short"....you don't have to accept this, you can change the definition in your EF model.

Comment: I'm surprised EF did this though because according to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/DataTypeMapping.html#n2 it should be mapped as an `int` (i.e int32)

Comment: NUMBER(5) is listed as int16, which ranges between -32000 and 32000

Comment: You mean in that link I gave? Second line at the top of the page (the Oracle to .NET mapping table) it says "NUMBER(2)..NUMBER(9)2 -> int Int32 System.Int32" That would be the mapping I'd have expected. Anyway you can easily change the definition in EF.

Comment: Although, to be fair, this contradicts it: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityEDMmapping.htm#ODPNT8275

Comment: yeap, sorry I looked at the wrong table. After changing it manually, it did not work.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you did you change it so I can't comment on whether you did it correctly or not, but it certainly should be possible change what the existing field is mapped to

Comment: What I did is went to my Model and change the type from short to int. Then got: The type 'Edm.Int16' of the member 'Field' in the conceptual side type 'Model.Field' does not match with the type 'System.Int32' of the member 'Field' on the object side type 'Project.Models.Field

Comment: sounds like you didn't finish updating all the parts then

Comment: sounds you are right. I should check if I need to have a look at other files.

Answer (score 0):

You should take this opportunity to upgrade your Oracle drivers and EF stack.

Oracle has shipped 100% managed code driver in a NuGet package called [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess).